# CSS: Having trouble aligning two flex elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex container with a background, and it contains some text consisting of vertically and horizontally center aligned content (page title) and absolute aligned content (breadcrumb).

Everything looks great when I have just the title, I've obviously got something messed up with the breadcrumb classes.

I would like the breadcrumbs to be right aligned and 25px from the top within the container (see example):

Any idea where it's going wrong?

```css
#site-wrapper {
  background: #ececec;
}
.site-wrapper-inner {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
}
.site-wrapper-inner.contained {
  max-width: 1500px;
}
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%; 
}
header .container, 
main .container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 30px;
  max-width: 1118px;
}
header.hero {
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 340px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
.container.hero-center {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 560px;
}
.breadcrumbs {
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
  font-size: 0.8em;
  align-self: flex-start;
  text-align: right;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  right: 0;
}
.breadcrumb-bg {
  padding: 0.2em 1em;
  background: rgba(19,71,91,0.7);
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<div id="site-wrapper">
  <div class="site-wrapper-inner container contained">
    <main id="main">
      <section>
        <header class="hero" style="background:#ccc;">
          <div class="breadcrumbs container"><div class="breadcrumb-bg">Breadcrumb</div></div>
          <div class="hero-center container">
            <h1>Center Aligned Content</h1>
          </div>
        </header> 
      </section>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>

<h1>Without Breadcrumb</h1>

<div id="site-wrapper">
  <div class="site-wrapper-inner container contained">
    <main id="main">
      <section>
        <header class="hero" style="background:#ccc;">
          <div class="hero-center container">
            <h1>Center Aligned Content</h1>
          </div>
        </header> 
      </section>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not `position: absolute;` on `.breadcrumbs`? I see you commented that out.

Comment: @MichaelCoker My mistake, forgot to uncomment it. I was trying to troubleshoot...

Comment: I think you need to start all over again. You have too much overlapping rules and it's very hard to fix it with just one or two lines.

Comment: You have applied 'hero' class with display:flex  on **header** tag. It's not a good idea.

Comment: @MichałDąbrowski Why not?

Comment: @JROB ahh, that's what I was going to suggest - use position absolute. but looks like someone else already suggested that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *absolute* position that you are using is being overwritten by the `position: relative` in this rule - `header .container, main .container`.

Override that with a more *specific* style and the alignment works fine:

```
header .breadcrumbs.container {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: auto;
}
```

See demo below:

```css
#site-wrapper {
  background: #ececec;
}
.site-wrapper-inner {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
}
.site-wrapper-inner.contained {
  max-width: 1500px;
}
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%; 
}
header .container, 
main .container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 30px;
  max-width: 1118px;
}
/*ADDED THIS*/
header .breadcrumbs.container {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: auto;
}
/**/
header.hero {
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 340px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
.container.hero-center {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 560px;
}
.breadcrumbs {
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
  font-size: 0.8em;
  align-self: flex-start;
  text-align: right;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  right: 0;
}
.breadcrumb-bg {
  padding: 0.2em 1em;
  background: rgba(19,71,91,0.7);
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<div id="site-wrapper">
  <div class="site-wrapper-inner container contained">
    <main id="main">
      <section>
        <header class="hero" style="background:#ccc;">
          <div class="breadcrumbs container"><div class="breadcrumb-bg">Breadcrumb</div></div>
          <div class="hero-center container">
            <h1>Center Aligned Content</h1>
          </div>
        </header> 
      </section>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>

<h1>Without Breadcrumb</h1>

<div id="site-wrapper">
  <div class="site-wrapper-inner container contained">
    <main id="main">
      <section>
        <header class="hero" style="background:#ccc;">
          <div class="hero-center container">
            <h1>Center Aligned Content</h1>
          </div>
        </header> 
      </section>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for that. It looks like a fantastic start. The only thing I see is that the breadcrumbs container floats to the right instead of the center, which puts the actual breadcrumbs background too far to the right. Any suggestions there?

Comment: you want the breadcrumbs align to the center too? the question says *right align*? :)

Comment: Yes I want them right aligned, but the container to be centered. If you look at the full page snippet you posted, notice the max-width for a container is 1118px, but the breadcrumb-bg floats all the way to the right. The 1118px container should align in the center, then the breadcrumb-bg floats to the right of that.

Comment: @JROB understood, check out the edited answer and let me know, thanks!

Comment: Man, that's great. Thanks a ton! I'm about done with my entire layout. Once it's done I wouldn't mind paying you to go through my css and clean it up a bit. I do the best I can, but I'm a backend dev.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is somehow your position: absolute is being overwritter by something else. just set an !important to you breadcumb class so it can get it.

Found it, the container class in your breadcrumb is overwriting it, you can either set !important to the position attribute of your breadcrumb class, or remove the container class of your breadcrumb element.